Every variable makes it to index.html except for one?
I'm doing a django project (I'm new to django). So far everything has been running smoothly except for one issue that I can't seem to figure out.
Here's my get method for Django:
class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'project/index.html'

    def get(self, request):
        allBrands = InventoryItem.objects.values_list('brand', flat=True).distinct().order_by('totalReviews')
        allAgeGroups = InventoryItem.objects.values_list('ageGroup', flat=True).distinct()

        items = InventoryItem.objects.all()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
      'items': items,
      'allBrands': allBrands,
      'allAgeGroups': allAgeGroups,
    })

Important Parts of index.html
{% extends "project/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% include "project/nav.html" with allBrands=allBrands allAgeGroups=allAgeGroups %}

<div>{{allAgeGroups}}</div>
<div>{{allBrands}}</div>

I am trying to get the information to nav.html
allBrands makes it just fine but allAgeGroups does not make it to index.html or nav.html
When I added 'allAgeGroups' I was running into the issue where for some reason the index.html was not receiving the information.
The query works.
When I print(allAgeGroups) in the get() function, I get nothing in the console
When I print(allAgeGroups) in the post() function, I get <QuerySet ['Adult', 'Youth']> in the console (what I want)
And I just realized I can remove everything from the render function, save the file, refresh the page, and everything still works???
What is happening?
Thank you.

What do you mean, you get "nothing"? Can you share the (important parts of the) index.html template?

This is also not how you are supposed to use a TemplateView.

minus one for lack of responsiveness.

I just updated my post to show you the important parts of index.html

are you sure call Index class in reuqest url??

Yes. The entire program works except for this variable making it through

You are calling the same model three times, although it seems unnecessary.
It’s better to try something like this:
views.py
class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'project/index.html'

    def get(self, request):
        items = InventoryItem.objects.all()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
      'items': items,
    })

index.html
{% extends "project/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
   {% include "project/nav.html" with items=items %}

   {% for item in items %}
      <div>{{ item.ageGroup }}</div>
      <div>{{ item.brand }}</div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

And don’t forget to register your TemplateView in urls.py.
